# Time series subset plot showing data outside of the subset range in R

Tags: r, csv, plot

First of all, very new to programming.

I'm working on an independent project to run regression on time series FED data. I have two tables: one is 2 year treasury yields (2YR) observed daily and the other is the DOW index observed daily. My DOW data only goes back to 2006, so I want to subset the rows from the 2YR that correspond with the dates I have DOW data.

When I create a new table in R, only the values for the subset are shown, but when I plot the data, it's plotting values from a time earlier than I need (data that isn't in the subset).

Below is my very messy work in progress:

```
setwd("/Users/efridge123/Desktop/R/Directory/Fed_Data")

yield <- read.table("tyield.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
djia <- read.csv("DJIA.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
DOW <- djia[,"VALUE"]
yield1 <- yield[-(1:7320), c("DATE", "DGS2")]
         **also tried..**
##yield1 <- yield[7321:9929, c("DATE","DGS2")]
yield1$DATE <- as.Date(yield1$DATE, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
dy2 <- cbind(yield1, DOW)
yield_time_series <- function(){
dy2$DOW <- NULL
plot(dy2, ylab = "2 Year Yield")
}
yield_time_series()
```

Below is a picture of the plot:

[image: As you can see, values from outside of the date range are being included.]

I suppose I could probably just extract a subset from 2YR and add it to DOW (here I did the opposite), but I would rather have working knowledge of how the problem can be resolved in R, so that in the future when I don't have the option, I have the knowledge.

Comment: I think you should `merge` your two data frames rather than `cbind`ing them. Try something like `df <- merge(DOW, yield1, by="DATE", all.x=TRUE)` and then plot `df`

Comment: apart from the solution proposed by @beginneR, it is always best to convert financial datasets to time series using the excellent `zoo` or `xts` packages, they make life so much easier. e.g. (http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/xts/docs/cbind.xts)